# Ubuntu 16.04 auth_pam broken

Tags: 16.04, mysql, email, postfix, pam

I'm trying to set up a mail server on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 machine but I can't get it to work properly.

I'm using a Postfix/Courier setup with MySQL for authentication.

Receiving emails and reading them using any email client (using POP3 and IMAP) works as expected but when I'm trying to send something all I get is a authentication error and these errors appear in the log:

```
saslauthd[29975]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_mysql.so): /lib/security/pam_mysql.so: undefined symbol: make_scrambled_password
saslauthd[29975]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_mysql.so
saslauthd[29975]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Module is unknown
saslauthd[29975]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=office@testubuntu1604.com] [service=smtp] [realm=testubuntu1604.com] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

This used to work perfectly in Ubuntu 14.04.

Are there any changes in Ubuntu 16.04 regarding PAM authentication I should know about?

Answer (score 5):

Using Courier's authdaemon works, but it is necessary to perform the following to make the courier authdaemon usable from within Postfix's chroot:

```
sudo service courier-authdaemon stop
sudo rm -rf /var/run/courier/authdaemon/ /var/spool/postfix/var/run/courier/authdaemon/
sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/var/run/courier/authdaemon/
sudo ln -s /var/spool/postfix/var/run/courier/authdaemon/ /var/run/courier/authdaemon
sudo service courier-authdaemon start
```

Then just include the following in /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: authdaemond
authdaemond_path: /var/run/courier/authdaemon/socket
mech_list: plain login
log_level: 9
```

source: https://www.hostsom.com/postfix-mysql-courier-imap-ubuntu-16-04-part3/

source: http://wiki.tolien.co.uk/Postfix_w/o_Maildrop#Courier-Authdaemon

(posting this as a new solution rather than a comment on the existing solution because I don't have the reputation to comment yet, and the existing solution was missing an important step)

Comment: +1mil man.....this shit is ridiculous.  Tonight all of our email functionality completely broke just fixed IMAP and SMTP was next. Your solution fixed it for me

Comment: Your answer has saved me after hours of research! All these postfix-courier-mysql guides are wrong for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Open and add these lines into `sudo vim /etc/default/saslauthd` file,

```
MECHANISMS="rimap" 
MECH_OPTIONS="127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand pam_mysql is no longer being developed and that particular feature in it was deprecated years ago, the new update finally "broke" it.  I have found no solution as of yet, other then migrating your authentication away from mysql, which for me isn't an option really, so still looking for a solution.

*update*: I just found this page, though I've not tested it out yet:
http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2016-04/msg23005.html

Comment: I gave those packages a shot but they didn't work. They kept throwing stack overflow errors. 

Moving away from MySQL wasn't an option so I migrated to Dovecot. This way I managed to keep the existing database with just a few alterations to the domains and users tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working IMAP server authentication setup, you can easily change postfix/saslauthd to use it instead of PAM:

"/etc/default/saslauthd":
MECHANISMS="rimap"
MECH_OPTIONS="127.0.0.1"

Answer (score -1):

If you use courier IMAP it's also possible to authenticate using its authdaemon like this https://www.hostsom.com/postfix-mysql-courier-imap-ubuntu-16-04-part3/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.